# Why is a particular concept constraint being duplicated in the generated template?

Tags: c++, g++, c++-concepts

I've just started experimenting with C++ concepts, using g++ 6.1.0 (Debian package version 6.1.1-1, flags `-std=c++17 -fconcepts`) and I've run into an error message I don't understand in the following reduced example:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename B>
concept bool ContextualBool = requires(B b) {
  { bool(b) };
  { !b } -> bool;
};

template <typename It>
concept bool InputIterator = requires(const It iconst, const It jconst, It i) {
  typename std::iterator_traits<It>::reference;
  typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type;
  { iconst == jconst } -> ContextualBool;
  { iconst != jconst } -> ContextualBool;
  { *i } -> typename std::iterator_traits<It>::reference;
  { ++i } -> It&;
  { *i++ } -> typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type;
};

template <typename P, typename Arg>
concept bool Predicate = requires(P pred, Arg x) {
  { pred(x) } -> ContextualBool;
};

template <typename P, typename It>
concept bool InputPredicate = requires {
  typename std::iterator_traits<It>::reference;
  requires Predicate<P, typename std::iterator_traits<It>::reference>;
};

/* Version 1 */
/*
InputIterator{I}
bool all_of(I begin, I end, InputPredicate<I> pred) {
*/
/* Version 2 */
/*
bool all_of(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end,
Predicate<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::reference> pred) {
*/
/* Version 3 */
bool all_of(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end,
            InputPredicate<InputIterator> pred) {
  while (begin != end) {
    if (!pred(*begin))
      return false;
    ++begin;
  }
  return true;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  if (all_of(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int n) { return n % 2 == 0; }))
    std::cout << "All elements of v are even\n";
  return 0;
}
```

In this code, both version 1 and version 2 compile successfully with the expected run-time results.  However, with version 3, I get the following error messages:

```
/tmp/concepts_repr.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/tmp/concepts_repr.cpp:56:70: error: no matching function for call to ‘all_of(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator, main()::<lambda(int)>)’
       if (all_of(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int n) { return n % 2 == 0; }))
                                                                      ^
/tmp/concepts_repr.cpp:44:10: note: candidate: template<class auto:1, class auto:2, class auto:3, class auto:4>  requires predicate( InputIterator<auto:1>) and predicate(InputPredicate<auto:2, auto:1>) and predicate(InputIterator<auto:3>) and predicate(InputPredicate<auto:4, auto:3>) bool all_of(auto:1, auto:1, auto:4)
     bool all_of(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end,
          ^~~~~~
/tmp/concepts_repr.cpp:44:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/tmp/concepts_repr.cpp:56:70: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘auto:2’
       if (all_of(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int n) { return n % 2 == 0; }))
                                                                      ^
```

From the error message, it looks like for some reason it's producing duplicate versions of the InputIterator and InputPredicate template parameters in the generated template.  I don't understand why this would be, especially given that version 2 worked.  Am I misunderstanding the statement from cppreference.com: "All placeholders introduced by equivalent constrained type specifiers have the same invented template parameter"?  Or is this possibly a bug in gcc?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather concepts operate on type names, not on concept names concept.  In version 3 of the code we have `InputPredicate<InputIterator>`, but `InputIterator` is a concept name, not a type name.  Hence the compile failures.

What we really want is for the `InputIterator` concept to operate on the type of `begin` and `end`.  We can accomplish this with a small change to the function signature:

```
bool all_of(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end,
        InputPredicate<decltype(begin)> pred) {
  ...
}
```

Alternatively, we can explicitly specify the template parameters and use a requires clause to place constraints on them:

```
template<typename It, typename P>
  requires InputIterator<It> && InputPredicate<P, It>
bool all_of(It begin, It end, P pred) {
  ...
}
```

I actually prefer the latter syntax, as I think it makes the intended constraint on deduced template parameters clearer.

Comment: `InputIterator` is being used as a placeholder when it appears in `InputPredicate<InputIterator>`, much the same as when it is used in the declarations of the `begin` and `end` parameters. It's not an error in and of itself, not even at the point of instantiation. [More placeholder examples.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed52e1581b78d9d4)

Comment: Interesting. Is there documentation that describes concepts as placeholders? I looked at the standards proposals but didn't see anything explicitly related to that use case.